# Converting 2 point to a line in ax+by+c=0

Tags: math, vector, geometry

I have been two points(x1,y1) (x2,y2)

I have to convert it to a equation of the form:
 Ax + By + C =0

I wish to write a function that takes the points as input and return the coeffcients A, B and C as output in the form of list.

**Is there some direct formula for A, B and C calculation in terms of the two points?**

Comment: This really belongs on math.se.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The slope of the line is `-A/B`, which is equal to `(y2-y1)/(x2-x1)`. So `A=y1-y2` and `B=x2-x1`. `C=x1*y2-y1*x2`.

Comment: The slope is `-A/B`, so you need to negate either `A` or `B` here.  `A = y1 - y2`, `B = x2 - x1`, `C = x1 * y2 - y1 * x2` works, for example.

Comment: Could you please edit your answer to include the fixes I mentioned?  As it stands, the answer is incorrect.  (Try it with some sample values of `x1`, `y1`, etc.)

Comment: Thanks.  I tweaked the equations so that they're even more correct!  +1.